# Pass data between two HTML pages (Google Apps Script)

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm trying to pass var 'id' from the page 'a.html' to 'b.html'. The var content comes from 'code.gs' as below:

code.gs

```
function data(){
var id = 1;

return id;
}
```

Next, I get this var and I show it in 'a.html':

a.html

```
<?
var id = data();
?>

<h1><?= id ?></h1>

<a href="b.html">Go to B.html</a>
```

By clicking 'Go to B.html', the system directs the user to there. I need to bring the same value of var 'id' from the page 'a.html' to 'b.html'.
Ps: searching for a little, I saw that there's a kind to send this var by the command 'localStorage', but it's not working for me. :(

Can anybody help me?

Comment: If you want to preserve a value between pages, you will have to use a form of (semi) persistent storage, such as the url query params, hash, cookies, Storage, etc.  The javascript variables in the page are not going to be persisted once the page is destroyed

Comment: can you show me an example how to do it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage here's the MDN as well!

Comment: Is b.html a `/exec` link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use localstorage
 a.html

```
localStorage.setItem('id',1)
```

b.html

```
var id  = localStorage.getItem('id')
```

the other way is to put it in a js file and import it in both html

Comment: It's not working. "ReferenceError: "localStorage" is not defined."

a.html
`
<?
var id = data();

localStorage.setItem('id', id) 
?>

<h1><?= id ?></h1>

<a href="b.html">Go to B.html</a>
`

b.html
`
<?
var id = localStorage.getItem('id')
?>

<h1><?= id ?></h1>
`

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: is javascript mut be put on the script tag   <script>
        localStorage.setItem('test', 1)
    </script>

    <script>
        let a = localStorage.getItem('test')
        console.log(a)
    </script>

Answer (score 1):

**Storing & Retrieving html data on the server**

```
Client Side JavaScript:
<script>
function saveId(v) {
  google.script.run.saveKeyValue({key:'id',value:v});
}
function getId() {
  google.script.run
  .withSuccessHandler(function(v){
     alert('The value is ' + v );
   })
  .getKeyValue('id');
}
</script>

Server Side Google Apps Script:

function saveKeyValue(obj) {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty(obj.key,obj.value);
}

function getKeyValue(key) {
  return PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty(key);
}
```

You could also replace PropertiesService with CacheService.

[Client To Server Communications](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

[Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)