# Google Sheets Script | Global Variable Loses Its Value After html sidebar/modal window

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Good day all,
I have a team vacation calendar.
The user presses the letter "v" to set a vacation date, to which the date of the vacation is stored in an external worksheet (used for other purposes, so I can't simply have a separate worksheet in the same spreadsheet).

The problem, a vacation date can either be "Paid" or "Banked" (for crediting later).
I use a modal Html window to ask the user which of the two, the vacation is.
However, global variables I set before opening the html modal window lose their value.
I need these global variables to store the row and column of the original entry (since the user clicking off the cell after typing "v" changes the value of getActiveCell().

What SHOULD happen:

1. user types "v"
2. html window pops up "which vacation type is this? banked or paid?
3. code enters the date of the vacation into the external spreadsheet.
4. code enters the "paid" or "Banked" value into the external spreadsheet.

I can get it to go as far as step 3 above, however, global variables are losing their values and there's no way to determine which cell the user originally clicked.

Step 1

[image: Step 1]

Step 2

[image: Step 2]

```
var selectedDateRangeRow;
var selectedDateRangeColumn;

function onEdit(e) {
  if (sheet.getRange("AH2").getValue() == true && sheet.getActiveCell().getValue() == "V") {
    selectedDateRangeRow = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
    selectedDateRangeColumn = sheet.getActiveCell().getColumn();
    ShowVacationMenu();
  }
}

function ShowVacationMenu() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('VacationType').setTitle("New Vacation Date");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "Select Vacation Type");
}

function AddDateToOverTimeSheet(selectedVacationType) {
  Browser.msgBox(selectedDateRangeRow);     //This global value returns empty/null.
}
```

html file:

```
<!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

```
<div class="container">

    <form action="#" name="vacation">
        <p>
            <input name="vacationType" type="radio" id="banked" value="Banked">
            <label for="banked">Banked</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            <input name="vacationType" type="radio" id="paid" value="Paid">
            <label for="paid">Paid</label>
        </p>
    </form>

    <p>
        <button id="submitBtn" class="btn waves-effect waves-light">Submit
  <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
</button>
    </p>
</div>

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<script>
    // 1. Find and store the element we want to listen to events on.
var submitButton = document.getElementById("submitBtn");

// 2. Create script function to run.
var onButtonClick = function() {
    if(document.forms.vacation.vacationType.value == ""){
      M.toast({html: 'Please select an option'});
    }else{

      //Create Array to store selected details
      var data=[
        document.forms.vacation.vacationType.value
       // exampe-of-new-item (no semicolon needed)
      ];

    google.script.run.AddDateToOverTimeSheet(data);
    google.script.host.close();
    };
};

// 3. Add the event listener for the element and function
submitButton.addEventListener("click", onButtonClick);
</script>
```

UPDATE:
I am now using the 'Properties Service' to pass variables between GAS and html, as follows:

```
function SelectVacationType(){

var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
userProperties.setProperty('CALENDAR_SHEET_ID', calendarSheetID);
userProperties.setProperty('PERSON_NAME', personName);
userProperties.setProperty('R', r);

  //Show Vacation Type Selector Window.
  ShowVacationMenu();

}


function ShowVacationMenu() {

var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('VacationType').setTitle("New Vacation Date");
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "Select Vacation Type");
}



function ImportData(data) {
//Retrieve First letter of first array item in 'data'
var selectedVacationType = data[0][0];

var userProperties = PropertiesService.getUserProperties();
var calendarSheetID = userProperties.getProperty('CALENDAR_SHEET_ID');
var personName = userProperties.getProperty('PERSON_NAME');
var r = userProperties.getProperty('R');

//open EXTERNAL Calendar sheet and go to the current person's sheet.
var calendarSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(calendarSheetID).getSheetByName(personName);
calendarSheet.getRange(r, 7).setValue(selectedVacationType); //<- this doesn't seem to work.

}
```

Comment: Since your user interface is not capable of collecting all of the required data then perhaps you should consider changing your entire approach.  How about building an html dialog that allows each person to provide all of the information at one time and then the press submit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The globals are lost because the `google.script.run` call executes the server-side script in a new instance that has no knowledge of the state of the original server-side instance.

When the flow is initiated at the client side, you can maintain state by creating an object in the client-side HTML/JavaScript code, passing it through the `google.script.run()` call to the server-side Apps Script code, and returning the possibly modified object back to the client side success handler. See [HTML Service: parameters and return values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values). Note that `Date` objects do not survive the round trip and must be encoded as text strings or some other way.

When the flow is initiated at the server side, you can pass values to the client through scriptlets in [templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates).

If you need to share state between server side instances for some reason, you can use the [Properties](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) service, or simply write and read data in spreadsheet cells whose location is known to all instances.

Comment: Very cool. Thank you. It's now 80% working using the Properties Service as you gave :) So light at the end of the tunnel perhaps. However, for some reason, now it only works randomly. Perhaps It needs some wait/pause to write and retrieve values? Sometimes it works and retrieves values, other times it doesn't and I can't figure out why.

Please See the updated main post :)

Comment: My pattern of choice completely avoids global variables. Instead, I always pass an object that contains the necessary data when calling the server from the client. See [Storing & Retrieving html data on the server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59653051/13045193) for one simple example.

Comment: How would it look in my example? would I use the google.script.run.saveKeyValue({key:'id',value:v}); in the html, then after google.script.close(). use the function getKeyValue(key) to retrieve the radio group selection?

Comment: See [HTML Service: parameters and return values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#parameters_and_return_values).

Comment: So It's working to the point of storing and retrieving variables. thanks :) However, the code that runs from google.script.run doesn't seem to run .setValue() commands. The update is what I have that runs after the html closes.

At the .setValue() it doesn't seem to do anything. Do you know why by chance?

Comment: First, Thank you for your patience and continued help. It is really appreciated bud.  The strangest thing is if I provide an absolute cell reference, the set value works! But if I’m specifying the row and column, based on a variable (even though the variables are outputting then correct values) it doesn’t work. Strange.    As for the execution log, it won’t let me run it unless I press the run button, and because it’s pulling data from an array, (data[0][0]) which is defined in the HTML, the execution log just says cannot read property ‘0’ of undefined.

Comment: I fixed it! it seems that using system properties stores variables as strings?  Because the value of r (variable) in my code seemed to be a string, so getrange(r,7) didn’t work. Setting the code to getrange(Number(r),7) fixed it. It now works! :)

Comment: You can access the **Executions** log by clicking the icon right above the gear icon ⚙︎ in the left-hand panel in the script editor.

Comment: Awesome. I didn't know that. Thank you that helps too. you've been brilliant. thank you for your help.